# Tuple variables - Can someone explain to me the following SQL statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT c1.address
FROM users c1, users c2
WHERE c1.address = c2.address
AND c2.first_name =  'John'
```

I don't understand what the third line is doing. I don't understand it because this query returns two separate addresses even though in the condition it says address 1 must match address 2?

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

The table has three records of users. two of those users share the same first name 'john'

**Edit:**

Also, why do we need to do this, instead of the following?

```
SELECT address
FROM users
WHERE first_name =  'John'
```

Comment: As far as I can tell that returns one address, not two.

Comment: Show us the tables structure + output of the query.

Comment: You should do some basic SQL tutorial, it will help you a lot more than asking here.

Comment: In particular, you should learn the JOIN syntax.  The querybas originally written used the "classic" syntax; JOIN is the modern syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you're only selecting the `address`, those selects are equivalent.  It returns two addresses because there are two "Johns".

Joining on address would allow you to figure you who *else* lives with John.  For example:

```
SELECT c2.first_name
FROM users c1, users c2
WHERE c1.address = c2.address
AND c1.first_name =  'John'
AND c2.first_name != 'John'
```

would tell you the names of everybody who lives with a "John".

Comment: "only selecting the address" as opposed to what?

Comment: @user521180: Selceting other fields such as the name.

Comment: even if I select address and name they still return the same thing. so what's the point of doing it like c1.address etc?

Comment: @user521180 If anybody lives with John, you can find them by selecting them as I have in my example.  That's why it's useful.  However, as you have them in your question, it's pretty useless.